# How to SUM only to a specific row in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to SUM() to a specific but variable row in excel.
I've tried dynamic ranges but didn't have much luck. I want to be able to insert rows in this range and have sum take account of the newly inserted values.

For example before inserting a new row the formula might look like this:

```
=SUM(A2:A3)
```

And after insertion the formula should look like this:

```
=SUM(A3:A4)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: that should be automatic

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by extending my range one row up:

```
=SUM(A1:A3)
```

Then, by inserting a row at `A2` the range does indeed extend automatically.